# php webservice doesn't handle multiple requests at the same time

Tags: php, mysql, apache, web-services

I developed a webservice (PHP/MySQL) that simply output a coupon code through a JSON string.

**How it works:** the application receives 1 parameter (email), it then makes a request to the database table to get a coupon code that has not yet been assigned. Then a request is made to update the row of this coupon code and put *"1"* in the assigned column. (SELECT / UPDATE routine)

After that, the JSON is outputed like this:

```
echo '{"couponCode": "'. $coupon_code . '"}';
```

That's all.

The problem is that the webservice receives 10000 requests in approx 1 minute. This occurs only one time a day. If I look in the raw logs of apache I can see that it has received exactly 10000 requests each time but in my table there's only 984 rows that has been updated (i.e.: 984 coupon codes given). I tested it multiple time and it varies between 980 and 986 each time. The log file created by the webservice doesn't show any errors and reflects exactly what has been updated in the database, between 980 to 986 new lines each time.

**My question is:** what happened with the missing requests? Is it the server that has not enough memory to handle such multiple requests in this short period of time? (When I test with 5000 requests it work OK)

If it can help, here's the function that get the a new coupon codes:

```
function getNewCouponCode($email){

$stmt = $this->connector->prepare("SELECT * FROM coupon_code WHERE email = '' ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1");
$stmt2 = $this->connector->prepare("UPDATE coupon_code SET email = :email WHERE id = :id");

try{

    $this->connector->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $this->connector->beginTransaction();
    $this->connector->exec("LOCK TABLES coupon_code WRITE");

    /*TRANSACTION 1*/
    $stmt->execute();
    $result["select"] = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    /*TRANSACTION 1*/

    /*TRANSACTION 2*/
    $stmt2->bindParam(":email", $email);
    $stmt2->bindParam(":id", $result["select"]["id"]);
    $result["update"] = $stmt2->execute();
    /*TRANSACTION 2*/

    $this->connector->commit();
    $this->connector->exec('UNLOCK TABLES');

    return $result;

}catch(Exception $e) {
    $this->connector->rollBack();
    $this->connector->exec('UNLOCK TABLES');
    $result["error"] = $e->getMessage();
    return $result;
}

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

986 requests per minute is a pretty significant load for a PHP application the way you've designed it, and an Apache web server.  It sounds like you're running this all on a single server.

First off, whatever is slamming you 10k times per minute should know to re-try later on if it gets a failure.  Why isn't that happening?  If that remote system is under your control, see if you can fix that.

Next, you'll find that the threading model of Nginx is much more efficient than Apache's for what you're doing.

Now, on to your application... it doesn't look like you actually need a `SELECT` and then `UPDATE`.  Why not just an update, and check the result?  Then it's atomic on its own and you don't have to do this table locking stuff (which is really going to slow you down).

Comment: Yes it's running on a single server. No the remote system is not under my control but I'll ask if there's any way to retry if it gets a failure. I'll definitely take a look at the threading model of Nginx. I tried with only an `UPDATE` but, this way, the same coupon code was assigned to different emails too often...

Comment: @LeoStein That shouldn't be possible if your query is correct.  `UPDATE coupon_code SET email = :email WHERE email='' LIMIT 1`  And, you should definitely have a second server anyway for redundancy and when you make code changes.

Comment: You're right, it looks like an `UPDATE` only works afterall. So I guess there's no easy fix for my problem, adding a second server for redundancy requires skills that, unfortunately, I don't have! Nginx also looks like something you need to have server admin knowledge to play with... Anyway, thanks for your time.

Comment: @LeoStein It's actually a very easy solution.  Change to UPDATE only and things will speed up significantly.  Installing Nginx along with PHP-FPM... there are many tutorials.  I'd suggest one but I don't know what OS you're using.  In any case, follow a tutorial for it and you'll be up and running in a half hour.  Adding a secondary server gets easy when you put Nginx out in front for load balancing.  Since most of your load is application based anyway, you could configure Nginx to use PHP-FPM on multiple servers with one line of config.  One step at a time and it will be more clear.